# Error: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination [NamespaceTypo] when I try create Signed APK

Tags: android

I Googled my problem but I can't find a solution.
When I try to create a signed APK, I get this error:

```
 Error:(6) Error: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination [NamespaceTypo]
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   Explanation for issues of type "NamespaceTypo":
   track these down.
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   obscure error messages. This check looks for potential misspellings to help
   Accidental misspellings in namespace declarations can lead to some very
```

This is the fragment of this layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@null"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right">
```

Answer (score 157, accepted):

change the code xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools" with this:

`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

It made mine work.

Comment: thanks for the feedback , I will keep it in mind from my next answer

Answer (score 15):

Your first two lines of the xml code are incorrect. The whole xml file should look as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:layout_behavior="@null"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right">
```

The first 2 lines are the declaration of the xml file. Although you are able to view the actual layout of the page in the design view, the layout itslef would still have issues when being built since it needs the xml tools tag.

The purpose of this namespace is to be able to record information in XML files, and have that information stripped when the application is packaged such that there is no runtime or download size penalty. It is a dedicated Android XML namespace.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

The `tools` namespace should be used for the preview tools of the xml on android studio. For example, if you are testing a view that is hidden by default, but you want to see it on your preview you should use `tools:visibility=visible`.

The `app` namespace, as far as I know, is used to add your custom views and layouts to the namespace of the xml you want to add your views.

So all your answers are correct, but I think no one explained what the namespaces do. So for convention I recommend to use them like this:

```
xmlns:yourAppName="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error. My problem was that Android Studio automatically put an xmlns into my layout tab instead of the root view tag when using data binding.

In other words when I have Android Studio resolve the `app` prefix it did this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"> <!-- added namespace here ... -->

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.ViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="..."
            android:layout_height="..."
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:backgroundResource="@{viewModel.someResource}"> <!-- ... when trying to resolve app -->
            ...
```

when it should have done this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.ViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools" <!-- should have added here -->
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="..."
            android:layout_height="..."
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:backgroundResource="@{viewModel.someResource}">
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

- change the attributes of tools in parent layout work for me like below**

  ```
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  ```

  **change this to the below**

  ```
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  ```