# New case: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination after migrating to androidx

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, namespaces, androidx

[image]I started a new project and because i wanted to use Mike Penz MaterialDrawer: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer which relies on the androidx support libs.

the migration went fine and i implemented the MaterialDrawer and also tested on my phone. later i noticed that the header layout i built which was fine, was displaying "Suspicious namespace and prefix combination" and code hinting was disable because android studio couldn't understand the prefix 'android:' anymore.

I've tried changing the schemas, cleaning gradle, invalidating cache, deleting .idea, .gradle, generated folders and rebuilding  but to no avail.

all the solutions here didn't work for me: [Error: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination [NamespaceTypo] when I try create Signed APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159322/error-suspicious-namespace-and-prefix-combination-namespacetypo-when-i-try-cr)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can use an older release if you don't want to use androidX yet. v6.0.9 for example still uses the support libraries. Related to the issue you are seeing. do you have the full build error output from gradle?

Comment: You also already tried to add `android.useAndroidX=true` and
`android.enableJetifier=true` to your local properties?

Comment: Yeah I did all that, fixed it by uninstalling and downloading a fresh Android studio, I also had to neglect all my saved settings. I think it was a corrupted AS thing, not your lib. Thanks though