# Android app with Menu Lint error when try to sign apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lint

I have this menu in my Android application:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:playtube="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_icon"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    playtube:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings_action_sleep_timer"
            android:title="@string/settings_sleep_timer_title"
            android:visible="false"
            playtube:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings_action_sdcard"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="@string/settings_sd_card_title"
            playtube:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings_action_hd"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="@string/settings_resolution"
            android:visible="true"
            playtube:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    </menu>
</item>
```

When I try to create a Signed APK I get this Lint error:

```
<issue
id="NamespaceTypo"
severity="Fatal"
message="Suspicious namespace and prefix combination"
category="Correctness"
priority="8"
summary="Misspelled namespace declaration"
explanation="Accidental misspellings in namespace declarations can lead to some very obscure error messages. This check looks for potential misspellings to help track these down."
errorLine1="    xmlns:app=&quot;http://schemas.android.com/tools&quot;"
errorLine2="               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~">
<location
    file="*/src/main/res/menu/main_activity_actions.xml"
    line="2"
    column="16"/>
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination \[NamespaceTypo\] when I try create Signed APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159322/error-suspicious-namespace-and-prefix-combination-namespacetypo-when-i-try-cr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove below code line from XML

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

and update your code like bellow and then try sign in it will work

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:playtube="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_icon"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        playtube:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/settings_action_sleep_timer"
                android:title="@string/settings_sleep_timer_title"
                android:visible="false"
                playtube:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/settings_action_sdcard"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:title="@string/settings_sd_card_title"
                playtube:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/settings_action_hd"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:title="@string/settings_resolution"
                android:visible="true"
                playtube:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```